# Need to call a js function when I clicks Stacked column chart

Tags: javascript, html, charts, highcharts, onclicklistener

I have using Highcharts Demo - Stacked column for my development. 
Please check the link: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked
,My requirement is, when I clicks on the columns, I need to call a js function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use build-in event handlers, see: http://jsfiddle.net/EHd32/

```
       plotOptions: {
            column: {
                events: {
                    click: function() {
                        alert('clicked!');    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: events: {
                    click: function(event) {
                        console.log(event.point.options.y);
         console.log(event.point.category);
      console.log(event.delegateTarget.name);
      console.log(event)
      
                    }
                }

Comment: Should I answer for that..?

Answer (score 0):

something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/RkQgu/)?

**code**

```
$("rect").on("click", function () {
    alert("click");
});
```